# How do I shift two UIViews 270px to the right in AutoLayout in code?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIView that is offscreen 400 pixels to the left and is 280 pixels wide.

I'm trying to shift the main UIView to the right 280 pixels and to have the offscreen UIView move onscreen to the right simultaneously like a sidebar.

I've been stuck here.

Is there a way to do this in code and to use NSLayoutConstraints?

Edit:

```
-(void) setUpSidebar{
  self.sidebarViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SidebarVC"];
  self.sidebarViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-400, 0, 280, self.sidebarViewController.view.bounds.size.height);
  [self.navigationController addChildViewController:self.sidebarViewController];
  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.sidebarViewController.view];
  [self.view insertSubview:self.sidebarViewController.view aboveSubview:self.view];
}

-(void)slideToTheRight{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.sidebarOpened = YES;
    //self.sidebarViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-280, 0, 280, self.sidebarViewController.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(280, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);



  }];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    self.sidebarViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(120, 0);
  }];
}

-(void) slideBack{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.sidebarOpened = NO;
    //self.sidebarViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-280, 0, 280, self.sidebarViewController.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
  }];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    self.sidebarViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-120, 0);
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. Make an IBOutlet to the constraint you want to change, and modify its constant parameter in code. So, if you had an outlet to a constraint to the left edge of the superview called leftCon, you do this:

```
self.leftCon.constant += 200;
```

Comment: How would you do a constraint to no visible superview?